# How to set the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files?

Tags: gdal

I want to wrap(re-project) one variable in this netcdf file.

```
D:\ gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 NETCDF:"C:\fie.nc":var "C:\Desktop\SM.img"
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv. Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
>
> ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed: EPSG:4326

I am using GDAL 1.9.0, released 2011/12/29. I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can edit the environment variables graphically in Windows (e.g., [this](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm), or [this](https://superuser.com/q/949560/79304)).

Add a System variable with name `GDAL_DATA` and value of the path to the shared GDAL data (a folder with a several files, like `coordinate_axis.csv`, `gcs.csv`, `pcs.csv`, and other files).

To make the environment variable effective, you need to run `cmd.exe`, or log-out, or other method.

See also: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQInstallationAndBuilding#HowtosetGDAL_DATAvariable

---

#### Anaconda / Miniconda users

GDAL library and command-line tools are available via (e.g.) `conda install gdal`

The `GDAL_DATA` variable is properly set when the environment is activated. This is done for you if you start an Anaconda Prompt, otherwise you can [activate the environment as documented](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment).

Comment: @DPSSpatial thanks, replace with an alternative resource.

Comment: I fixed my problem based on your solution but I got new error message,
"ERROR 1: Failed to process SRS definition: ESPG:3857" How fix this problem now?

Comment: @PredatorX can you find/open `%GDAL_DATA%\pcs.csv`? Does the folder have any special file permissions that may limit it's access?

Comment: Yes, I checked that GDAL_DATA folder had read-only permission, I unchecked read-only permission moreover I changed security level for users also, and I'll check again as soon as possible if it fixed I'll write here fixed, thank you @MikeT

Comment: it fixed that previous error but I got new error message "Unable to find driver `PostgreSQL'." this new problems is annoying I did upgrade GDAL to latest version 2.3.1 but it didn't fix, My PostgreSQL is 9.5.3 64 and latest version of OsGeo4W64

Comment: My GDAL is saved under the Home directory. Do I still need to use a system variable or can I use a User variable? It doesn't seem to be working as a user variable

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the --config switch:

```
D:\ gdalwarp --config GDAL_DATA "D:/my/gdal/data" -t_srs EPSG:4326 NETCDF:"path":Soil_Moisture "C:\Desktop\SM.img"
```

See: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions

for information on config options.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to set the `GDAL_DATA` variable programmatically (C#) and @turgay's solution didn't work for me. [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/When-does-the-env-var-GDAL-DATA-get-processed-td3753192.html) I found the working way:

```cs
OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_DATA", path+@"\gdal\data");
```

Comment: Didn't work for me but upvoted it as it is a different solution from other provided here.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use for making programmatically (with C# API).
Sample code:

```cs
string path = @"C:\abc\";
_SetValueNewVariable("GDAL_DATA", path + "\\data");
_SetValueNewVariable("GEOTIFF_CSV", path + "\\data");
_SetValueNewVariable("GDAL_DRIVER_PATH", path + "\\gdalplugins");

private static void _SetValueNewVariable(string sVar, string sValue)
{
    if (System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(sVar) == null)
    {
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(sVar, sValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On the command prompt, I used to set the GDAL_DATA path by pointing to where (and which gdal-data) to use:

> set GDAL_DATA=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\gdal-data

I learned it from http://clhenrick.github.io/thesis-blog/procrastination/portfolio-work/2014/09/27/procrastinating/ I always needed to do the above even though I already set it up in my environment variables. My problem seemed to be an installation issue but I didn't want to reinstall anything...yet.

As a temporary solution, while I did not have time for a more permanent one, I deleted the existing GDAL_DATA path in my environment variables, shut down the computer, turned it on, created a new one, shut down the computer, turned it on again. FIXED!

Complete shut-down not restart due to the quirky behaviour of my system.

Comment: The thing with "complete shut-down not restart" saved my life