# Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.\ setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable

Tags: python, conda, gdal

I try to work with GDAL library and receive this error:

```
ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
```

I founded those solutions
    [How to set the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444310/how-to-set-the-gdal-data-environment-variable-to-point-to-the-directory-containi)

so I change my working enviroment, the path to GDAL-DATA folder and nothing help.

then, I saw this one: [How to fix the enviroment variable GDAL_DATA path set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883445/how-to-fix-the-enviroment-variable-gdal-data-path-set)
and for right now it's working but now I have to define the path to GDAL_DATA folder every time.

```
import os
import ospybook as pb
from ospybook.vectorplotter import VectorPlotter

#Theese two lines are the new solution from the 2nd link that I want to stop adding at the begining of each code
# os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = r'C:\Users\royanc\Anaconda3\Library\share\gdal'
# os.environ['proj'] = r'C:\Users\royanc\Anaconda3\Library\share'

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\royanc\Desktop\ospybook\osgeopy-data\global')

# Plot populated places on top of countries from an interactive session.
vp = VectorPlotter(True)
vp.plot('ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shp', fill=False)
vp.plot('ne_50m_populated_places.shp', 'bo')
```

I'm using pycharm 3.6, conda version 4.7.10, python 3.7 on win 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using PyCharm you could set the environment variable in you Run Configuration

Go to `Run -> Edit Configurations` and set your GDAL_DATA variable here

[image: how to set gdal data]

This still requires you to set up the configuration for each project, however it keeps system specific configurations out of your code.