# rasterio is looking for gcs.csv which does not exist in gdal anymore

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, rasterio

### description

I'm using [geemap](https://github.com/giswqs/geemap) to display a raster on a created map.
This lib use `xarray_leaflet` to display the raster and this lib will end up using `rasterio` to manipulate the .tif file.

When I launch my display :

```
m = geemap.Map()
m.add_raster(clip_map, colormap='terrain', layer_name='gfc')
```

I get the following error :

> CRSError: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.

This error is everywhere on SO so I tried to verify if my GDAL_DATA env variable was coorectly set :

```py
import os
import stat
gdal_data = os.environ['GDAL_DATA']
print('is dir: ' + str(os.path.isdir(gdal_data)))
gcs_csv = os.path.join(gdal_data, 'gcs.csv')
print('is file: ' + str(os.path.isfile(gcs_csv)))
st = os.stat(gcs_csv)
print('is readable: ' + str(bool(st.st_mode & stat.S_IRGRP)))

# out 
# is dir: True
#is file: False
#FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/gdal/gcs.csv'
```

going to the glad distrib inb the `NEWS` file, I read that they removed lots of file in 3.0 including `gcs.csv`. So it's no longer included in my folder.

Is there a workaround ?

### setup

```
rasterio==1.1.5  
python==3.6  
geemap==0.7.9  
gdal==3.0.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue of rasterio (in conda for example)

Answers are given in

- [Where is “ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv” coming from and what does it mean?](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html)
- [How to set the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14465201)
- [ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284709/error-4-unable-to-open-epsg-support-file-gcs-csv)
- [Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv #1539](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/1539)
- [Missing gcs.csv file](https://inbo.github.io/niche_vlaanderen/faq.html#missing-gcs-csv-file)

and many more.

Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment to a path which contains a gcs.csv file (use search to find a path)

```
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = '.../site-packages/rasterio/gdal_data'
```

Or

```
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = '..../site-packages/fiona/gdal_data'
```

thanks to [@gene](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2581/gene) for the answer